# Lagrangian Optimization: equality constraint vs inequality constraint?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

For minimization problem

$minimize$  $x_1+x_2$ with constraint $x_1^2+x_2^2-2=0$

How does it differ from

$minimize$  $x_1+x_2$ with constraint $-x_1^2-x_2^2+2 \geq 0$ ?

For the equality constraint, I got the Lagrangian

$\mathcal{L}(x_1,x_2,\lambda)=x_1+x_2+\lambda(x_1^2+x_2-2)$

and the KKT conditions

$1+2\lambda x_1=0$

$1+2\lambda x_2=0$

$x_1^2+x_2^2-2=0$

So I got possible points are $(1,1),(-1,-1)$, and indeed $(-1,-1)$ is the minimizer.

Is there any difference with $\geq$ inequality?

Comment: The Lagrange method will only tell you about the extrema on the _boundary_ of the region, in this case, a constraint _circle_ centered on the origin with radius $ \ \sqrt2 \ \ . $  The inequality means that you also need to look for any local extrema (critical points) of the function in the _interior_ of the disk defined by that inequality.  (For the given linear function, there are none.)

Comment: For example, change the objective to $x_1^4 + y_1^4  $  on the same disc

Comment: For inequalities introduce a slack variable to make the constraint an equality e.g. $-x_1^2-x_2^2+2 - s^2 = 0$. [Example Paper][1].


  [1]: https://users.wpi.edu/~pwdavis/Courses/MA1024B10/1024_Lagrange_multipliers.pdf